# Can not Deserialize Json string

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, json.net

I have a json response below

```
{"data":[{"name":"Shi","gender":"male","id":"5288","picture":{"data{"url":"https:\\/fbcdnprofile-a.\/hprofile-ak-frc3\/t1.0\/p50/551182_10152227358459008_326007305_n.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}}{"name":"Nagarajan","gender":"male","id":"557811","picture":{"data":{"url":"https:\/\/fbcdnprofilea.akamaih\/hprofile-ak-xpf1\/t1.0-1\/c8.0.50.50\/p50x5\/10389990_10152395979004812_6804136212372558329_n.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}}
```

I want to Deserialize it, my code block is

```
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

 FaceBookFriendsModel friedDATA= js.Deserialize<FaceBookFriendsModel>(friendsData);
```

and my FaceBookFriendsModel is

```
 public class FaceBookFriendsModel
{
    List<fbFriends> data { get; set; }
}
```

and fbFriends class is

```
public class fbFriends
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string gender { get; set; }
  public long id { get; set; }
  public picture picture { get; set; }

}
```

picture  class is

```
 public class picture
  {
      public data data { get; set; }
  }
```

i am getting null in friedDATA

Comment: "i am getting null in friedDATA": are you sure your code is executed? There is no way the Deserialize method can return null; either it returns an object, or it throws...

Comment: BTW, your JSON is invalid; it can't be deserialized if it's not well formed.